# Usage of a phrase: "like hell"

Tags: phrases, punctuation, commas

Edited:
**"Like hell, I'll be there."
"Like hell I'll be there."**

I'd appreciate fellow English speakers' opinion on how different these two sentences above sound.

The only difference here is the comma (used in the first sentence and not used in the second).

I believe it changes the meaning completely as "like hell, I'll be there" is interpreted as "hell yea, I will be there", considered as an affirmative response to a question or an invitation, while "like hell I'll be there" should be understood as having a scornful/ironic undertone to it, meaning "I am not gonna be there at all", thereby saying the exact opposite of "like hell, I'll be there". What o you guys think?
What is the difference between "like hell**,** I'll be there" and "like hell I'll be there"?

Thank you! :D

Comment: What two sentences above?

Comment: oops, my mistake! Forgot to add the sentences haha. Thank you for pointing out, Hot Licks.

Comment: You are correct -- the comma changes the perceived meaning, for most readers.  I'd note that the version with the comma is far less idiomatic.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply, Hot Licks. For others, please feel free to leave comments. I'd appreciate any inputs.

Comment: No native speaker would ever say the first one; there's no comma intonation in the idiom. The idiom is _Like hell `S`_ where `S` is some assertion being denied vehemently. _Like hell_ is different from [_the hell_ and other _hell_ idioms](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/thehell.html).

Comment: To me, neither version indicates that you are keen to be there: quite the opposite. If it is something you like, compare it with heaven, not hell. "That will be heaven." And considering that yours is spoken dialog, where is a comma? Anyway, adding a comma only emphasises the denial. "Like hell, I'll be there" means "As with hell, I won't be there." OTOH "Hell, yes!" is unambiguous. It says "yes."

Comment: @JohnLawler - I browsed Ngram for several minutes and found several examples of the first (though admittedly they were rare).  Made sense, in context, when taken to mean "I'll ignore any advice otherwise and be there/do that regardless".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comma breaks the meaning up, as you've described.

"Like hell, I'll be there" would indicate that you will be at a specific place, just as hell will also be at that place. This phrase with the commas is not idiomatic in writing or speech.

"Like hell I'll be there" would emphatically deny that you will be at a specific location. This is the normal usage found in writing and speech. [See it in the Idiom dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/like+hell)

As in all languages, context is everything. And in modern typing, commas are not to be trusted.

So, if you wrote an email to your boss and said "Will you be at the IT meeting?" and he replied, "Like hell, I'll be there," you'd want to know how well your boss gets along with IT before making an assumption about what he meant by his email. The comma is not normally associated with the phrase and it could have easily been placed due to sloppy punctuation.

Comment: Other sexual, religious or toilet profanities than 'hell' can be used after 'like', including 'fuck', 'shit', and, particularly in Britain, 'buggery'. Such usages, including 'like hell', are severely informal, and likely to be considered inappropriate in a formal or business context.

Comment: I'm not persuaded that all those who use either of these, understand the subtlety of the difference as described.